# Explain something: anything

Tags: meaning, word-usage, some-any

*Any* seems synonymous with *some* in some examples, such as "Is anyone home?".  And *any* seems synonymous with *every* in some examples below, and definitely not in others.

**On the internet I encountered a German who asked me what the difference is between "some" and "any".  I didn't have a really good answer.  What I have after thinking about it further is only a bunch of examples (see below).  How might one best explain "any" to a foreigner learning English?**

> - **Any** six-year-old can do that
> - **Every** six-year-old can do that
> - The answer to that question can be found in **any** book on geology.
> - The answer to that question can be found in **every** book on geology.

These are more-or-less synonymous.  So *any* might appear to mean the same thing as *every*.

> If any member is absent, the meeting will be canceled.
>   If some member is absent, the meeting will be canceled.

In this pair of sentences, *any* is more akin to *some* than to *every*.

"Does anyone believe that?" This is somewhat like "Is there someone who believes that?".  It certainly doesn't mean *every*.  Similarly "Is anyone home?".

> There was never any doubt about that.

I suspect *not any*, *never any*, and any number of negative words seem to play a role that must be included in the account of the use of *any*.  (And that means it must be included in ***every*** such account— another instance of *any* appearing to mean *every*.)

> - She can order anything on the menu.
> - She can order everything on the menu.
> - She can order something on the menu.

and

> - You can cash this check at any bank.
> - You can cash this check at every bank.
> - You can cash this check at some bank.

In these cases, *any*, *every*, and *some* have three quite distinct meanings.

> - You cannot cash this check at any bank.
> - You cannot cash this check at every bank.

The first of these examples is like the "never any doubt" above.

"Anyone can do that" might mean "Everyone can do that" but "Can anyone do that?" means "Can someone do that?".

> - Any remembered instance of the old custom is mistaken for a monstrous accident.
> - Every remembered instance of the old custom is mistaken for a monstrous accident.

The first sentence above is quoted from a book by C. S. Lewis.  *Any remembered instance* seems to imply (among other things) that he's being deliberately non-committal about whether there even is any remembered instance.

> - Does anyone know a good mechanic?
> - Does everyone know a good mechanic?
> - Does someone know a good mechanic?

It could be anywhere.
It could be everywhere.

He arrived 30 minutes earlier than any other guest.
He arrived 30 minutes earlier than every other guest.
He arrived 30 minutes earlier than some other guest.

If any citizen so wishes, the council will make that information available.
If every citizen so wishes, the council will make that information available.

I will vote for any candidate who opposes the incumbent.
I will vote for every candidate who opposes the incumbent.
I will vote for some candidate who opposes the incumbent.

How to convince anybody of anything.
How to convince everybody of everything.
How to convince somebody of something.

This is worse than anything that could happen.
This is worse than everything that could happen.
This is worse than something that could happen.

Such an affront would make an enemy of anyone.
Such an affront would make an enemy of everyone.
Such an affront would make an enemy of someone.

If you find anyone who knows the answer to that question, let me know.
If you find everyone who knows the answer to that question, let me know.
If you find someone who knows the answer to that question, let me know.

Learn any language in two weeks!
Learn every language in two weeks!
Learn some language in two weeks!

The government wants the power to shut down any web site.
The government wants the power to shut down every web site.
The government wants the power to shut down some web site.

> 1. A Wikipedian is any person who edits Wikipedia.
> 2. A Wikipedian is every person who edits Wikipedia.
> 3. Any person who edits Wikipedia is a Wikipedian.
> 4. Every person who edits Wikipedia is a Wikipedian.

Notice the distinct difference in meaning between sentences 2 and 4 above: the second one is nonsense; the fourth is true.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question was down-voted?

Comment: Take an uncommented downvote to mean _This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful_, like it says on the downvote button and then add on _and I can't bothered to help the questioner improve it_. (wasn't me, in fact I'm just about to upvote it because I think it is quite interesting)

Comment: Personally, I think you have included far too many examples. I would select the ones that for you are most relevant and unequivocally illustrate your case.

Answer (score 6):

*Any* is a [***Negative Polarity Item***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68253/15299), and thus requires a negative context.
*Some* is **not** an NPI, and quite often *some* and *any* in complementary distribution

- *I know he bought **some**, but he **doesn't** have **any** left.*

However, some constructions, like questions, allow either *some* or *any*.

- *Did he eat any breakfast?*
- *Did he eat some breakfast?*

Both of these questions are grammatical, and anyone who'd like to explain their difference  --
if any -- in precise terms which apply to **any** sentence (not just this one) is welcome to try.
My impression is that there's no systematic difference in meaning.

For more details, see Robin Lakoff's 1969 paper

> "[Some Reasons Why There Can't Be Any *some-any* Rule](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/411442?uid=3739960&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104098861437)"

Comment: It appears that this particular way of using "any" requires a negative context, and "not any" means "none", "There's never anybody who knows the answer" means it's always the case that nobody knows, etc.  But the way in which you use any when you say "terms which apply to _any_ sentence" appears to me to be quite another matter.

Comment: It appears that Lakoff is writing only about conditional, negative, and interrogative sentences.  Perhaps those are precisely the ones in which "any" is a negative-polarity item.  But in many of my examples, it seems to be something else, so his paper wouldn't apply to those.

Comment: That's the "free-choice" _any_, which has different syntax and normally requires a "possible" modal: _Anybody **can** do that_ vs **Anybody did that*. This is often called "Possible-Polarity _any_". For further discussion, see Zeno Vendler's "Each and Every, Any and All". (Oh, btw, Robin Lakoff's paper is "her paper".)

Comment: Apologies to Robin Lakoff.  I've encountered both male and female Robins.

Comment: The negative polarity phenomenon does not seem to be a rule so much as a generalisation, as you very quickly find out when you start teaching: *I like some Bob Marley songs. I like any Bob Marley songs. I don't like some Bob Marley songs. I don't like any Bob Marley songs*.  Sometimes I feel that *some* indicates the speaker has a range of identities/quantities in mind and *any* indicates the range is unbounded. Just an opinion though.

Comment: First, negative polarity _any_ is usually unstressed. In _I don't like some Bob Marley songs_, if you mean there are only a few, then _some_ will be stressed, and you can move it out of the negative scope (_There are some Bob Marley songs I don't like_), in which case you don't have to stress _some_. Negative polarity _any_ can't be moved out of the negative scope: _There are any Bob Marley songs I don't like_ is ungrammatical. _Some_ isn't negative polarity, which means it can occur inside or outside a negative scope -- it's not affected; it's _any_ that's the NPI.

Comment: @JohnLawler *How about Bring in any strangers you find walking around outside*. Or *You've lost any chance you had of winning the competition* ?

Comment: @Araucaria: The first one is a "free-choice" sense of _any_ that can occur with modals instead of negatives: _Pick any one you want, Anybody can do that, That's a good boat for anybody_. The second one is negative; _lost_ means 'don't have any more'. Try it with _find_: _*You've found any chance you had of winning the competition_.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than worrying about when they are synonymous and when not, why not focus on what they actually mean?

`Every` refers to all members of the class.

`Some` refers to a subset of the members of the class (at least one, but not all). (If the noun is singular, as in your last example, "some website", it refers to a subset with only one member. Someone and somebody are singular.)

`Any` refers to any specific member of the class, selected at random.

---

The usage of the compound words formed from these follow from the above. For example:

Since `Everyone` refers to all members of the class, it **refers to all members of the class**--it is used with a singular verb but all members of the class are in view.

`Someone` only refers to one individual. There may be multiple individuals that satisfy the criteria, but only one is needed.

Depending on context, `Anyone` may be satisfied by a single individual or by as many as meet the criteria. Its range of meaning is bounded by that of someone (a single member) and everyone (all members). Depending on context it could be equivalent to either:

"Bring me `anyone` in the audience wearing a red tie." is the same as:
"Bring me `everyone` in the audience wearing a red tie."
(In either case, all members of the audience wearing a red tie would be brought to him.)

But:
"Does anyone know a good mechanic?" means the same as:
"Does someone know a good mechanic?"
(Only one person need respond to meet the speakers' needs.)

And again:
"If any citizen so wishes, the council will make that information available." is different from:
"If every citizen so wishes, the council will make that information available."
In the former case, any random member of the class of citizen may request the information. In the latter, **every** member must make the request before the information is made available.

Comment: "Bring me anyone in the audience wearing a red tie." is *not* the same as "Bring me everyone in the audience wearing a red tie." The former means, find one person who satisfies the criteria, and bring that that person to me. The latter means "Bring all people who meet this criteria"

Comment: But I do like the approach mentioned before the break.

Comment: That's why I included the break. Everything after that gets a bit rambly. I do not believe it's actually possible to determine, without context, what the first of those sentences means (despite my assurances above). It could mean bring anyone that meets those criteria (i.e. everyone found), or it could mean just bring one person. It depends what is actually being asked for: A single volunteer, everyone that violated dress code with their flashy red ties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tell him that "any" is mainly used with a negative verb or in questions, "some" is for positive sentences where they can be reversed into a question using "any", and "every" is pretty much "every"thing else.

That might be confusing, but going into extreme detail will confuse him more. Any time you're talking to someone a bit less experienced than you are, it's helpful to overgeneralize everything in order to make sure at least some information makes it through.

Comment: This answer seems to ignore many of my examples.  If I say "Anyone can understand this", it's not negative or interrogative.

Comment: But you can't make a rule in English without a billion exceptions.

Comment: I don't think these are just _exceptions_.  They're far to big a part of the picture for that.

Comment: "I before e" has a lot of big _exceptions_ too. Diving too deep into an explanation wouldn't be beneficial to someone who's just now learning the language.

Comment: But I don't think these are exceptions.  I think they also obey a rule.  But it's a different rule.

Comment: So many rules... Why does he want to learn English anyway?

Comment: Much depends on the German speaker's level of English. If he is a beginner, then Jamie's guidelines will be more helpful (initially), if instead he is an advanced learner, he might have noticed these discrepancies in English native speakers or in texts, in which case Hardy's examples might help.