# Is the action "had ever" understandable

Tags: tenses

What is the correct use "had ever" or "have never" tried it? Are both acceptable? The quote my question comes from is, "Marijuana use seems to be hovering, with about 36 percent of students saying they **had ever** tried it." "Had ever" just doesn't seem to come together correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of “ever” in non-negated sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/use-of-ever-in-non-negated-sentence). Only Tolkien seems to have broken its negative-polarity status acceptably in recent-ish years. You need 'only' before 'about 36%'. And ' ... **have** ever ...'.

Answer (score 0):

'**Ever**' is not needed in the sentence after '**had**'.

> Marijuana use seems to be hovering, with about 36 percent of students
>   saying they **had** tried it.

Alternatively the negative of the sentence would use '**had never**'

> Marijuana use seems to be hovering, with about 64 percent of students
>   saying they **had never** tried it.

Comment: If you ***had ever*** stopped to consider this closely, you would realize that the construction sometimes *is* quite commonplace and unobjectionable.

Comment: @Robusto But that's "ever" in a conditional's if-clause, and the OP isn't about them, it's about *statements*.

Comment: @RosieF: Doesn't matter. My statement that it is "commonplace and unobjectionable" stands, even in the use case you cite.